# Casio fx-85gt plus scientific calculator, difference between binary and unary minus?

Tags: binary-operations, calculator

So in my new physics class when telling us how to deal with exponents on the calculators he said that when using the $\times10^x$ button you must use the unary minus operator which looks like a minus in brackets, I asked him why as all the time I've used it I've just ignored that button, he basically didn't give an answer. I'm curious if I should adopt this button or just continue on my way using the binary operator for everything... I looked in the manual and there doesn't seem to be a reference to it I could find, and the threads I looked at seemed to be focused on different calculators. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Unary minus is to negate an expression. Binary minus is a subtraction operator. So your teacher is correct, at least conceptually. Even if your calculator blurs the distinction, others may be using different calculators for which the distinction matters.

Comment: @quasi so in this case the difference between $n\times10^−5$ and $n\times10^-5$ are effectively doing the same thing, however on some calculators this would fail?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing as you say only in ALG mode. In RPN mode, instead, $-$ is used to effectively perform the subtraction of the previously entered operands, while $(-)$ is used to start entering a new negative number.